# Password Cracker (brute force)

Tags: c++, strings

**THIS IS JUST FOR LEARNING PURPOSES. I WON'T BE USING THIS TO HACK ANYONE.**

Here is a small algorithm I made to crack a password. This is just the background of a more complex code I'm going to make.

To be honest, this code is TERRIBLY written, so I need help on making it more efficient and flexible. It is limited to 5-characters password and not easy to expand.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

std::string checkCharacters = {
    '%',
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
    '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'
};

std::string search(std::string password) {
    for (int a = 0; a < checkCharacters.size(); a++)
        for (int b = 0; b < checkCharacters.size(); b++)
            for (int c = 0; c < checkCharacters.size(); c++)
                for (int d = 0; d < checkCharacters.size(); d++)
                    for (int e = 0; e < checkCharacters.size(); e++)
                    {
                        std::string checkString = "";
                        checkString += checkCharacters[a];
                        checkString += checkCharacters[b];
                        checkString += checkCharacters[c];
                        checkString += checkCharacters[d];
                        checkString += checkCharacters[e];

                        checkString.erase(std::remove(checkString.begin(), checkString.end(), '%'), checkString.end());

                        if (checkString == password)
                            return checkString;
                    }

    return "TARGET_PASSWORD_NOT_FOUND";
}

int main() {
    while (1) {
        std::string password;
        std::cout << "Enter password : ";
        std::cin >> password;
        std::cout << "Your password is : " << password << std::endl;
        std::string attempt = search(password);
        std::cout << attempt << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generating all the possible passwords (if this is what you need for your other use-cases) is a special case of a more general problem: make all subsets of length `k` from a set of size `n`. It might be a good learning experience to try to write such a general code for example using a simple recursive method and with templates to make your method work for arbitrary sets and arbitrary password-lengths `k`.

Comment: @Winther, or one can just use `std::next_permutation` in a loop

Comment: @Incomputable That won't work here. `std::next_permutation` gives you the next permutation of the current word but it does not add or remove letters from the word.

Comment: @Dat I don't think anybody is worried about you cracking passwords with this. It would take longer than the current existence of the universe before it cracked any real password system.

Comment: how to chage delay status / live count.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a critique, and a rewrite of the code you showed, that is, the code for checking if a given password only contains characters from a given character set; for an actual brute force password cracker, see e.g. [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44620/brute-force-password-cracker)  question.

---

I think you should look at the problem a bit differently.

Why don't you go through the characters in the password, and check if every character is in the set of allowed characters? 
If you get that every character of the password is in the set of allowed characters, then the password is valid, otherwise it isn't.

I'd implement this in the following way.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<numeric>

const static std::set<char> charSet = {
    '%',
    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
    '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'
};

bool checkPassword(const std::string password) {
  return std::accumulate( password.begin(), password.end(), true,
    [](bool acc, char c) { return acc && charSet.find(c) != charSet.end(); } );
}

int main() {
  for (;;) {
    std::string password;
    std::cout << "Enter password : ";
    std::cin >> password;
    std::cout << "Your password is : " << password << std::endl;
    if(checkPassword(password)) {
      std::cout << "VALID" << std::endl << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "INVALID" << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This will work with passwords of any length. 
Set [lookups](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) have logarithmic complexity, so checking a password of length \$n\$ given a character set of size \$m\$ should be \$\mathcal O(n\cdot \log(m))\$.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That's why I wrote 'linear time in its [the password's] length'! Isn't checking a password actually \$O(Nlog(M))\$, since set lookups have logarithmic complexity? Oh my... why did I write that sets have constant lookup time.. thanks for making me notice that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you again, it should be fixed now.

Comment: One other point: instead of using `std::accumulate`, I'd probably use `std::all_of` here. `return std::all_of(pw.begin(), pw.end(), [](char c) { return charSet.find(c) != charSet.end(); });`

Comment: It would be better to use a [`std::bitset`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), and just check whether the bit is set. Smaller and vastly more efficient.

Comment: Why is your `checkPassword` taking its `string` argument by value?

Comment: What does your rewrite have to do with the original "cracking" code?  You seem to have written a completely different problem, that of ensuring an entered password is composed entirely of allowed characters.  I think you misread the original:  He *generates* passwords from the list of allowed characters, then see if each candidate is equal to the correct password.

Comment: What is with the recent interest in this 4 year old answer? I mean.. feel free to edit it, if you can improve it (I'm sure there are plenty of things to improve). This answer has been accepted, which would make me misunderstanding the original question rather unfortunate, if not strange. I agree that it is possible, however I really don't see the point discussing this 4 years after the OP accepted this answer.